# Importing existing project in other computer gives me errors

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I used this method.

File->Import->General->Existing Projects into Workspace, Next Select root directory: /path/to/project Projects-> Select All UNCHECK both "Copy projects into workspace" and "Add project to working sets" Finish

I got a error in all my Classes. In the `onCreate` method, `setContentView(R.layout.main);`
The error is:

> R cannot be solved to a variable and main cannot be resolved or is not
>   a field.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: may be it's a corrupted project :)

Comment: Is it _R.class_ generated? Try clean project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project, and take 'android tools', 'Fix Project Properties'.

Then clean the project. If yet not recovered, repeat the steps by configuring the build path by reordering it..

Hope this might help you..! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Project -> Clean

Maybe it can solve problem

Answer (score 0):

Probaby the R class is not yet generated by SDK. When you open any of your layouts (xml files) change it ( adding a space is enough ;) )and save it, the R class is re-generated with ids of all your elements from layouts. It is common problem when moving projects or checking out from svn. Re-generations of the files in /gen folder is forced when you change layout files. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Well I make it work. If anyone is having this issue open your project with notepad and copy it. Then make a new project in Eclipse and past all your info.

Don't know why but its the only way it works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update SDK location if needed. Sometimes when you take a project
   from one computer to another you need to update the SDK location.
   Open project properties->'Java Build Path'  and search for errors,
   especially in the libraries tab.  Make sure that all the resources
   are present.
2. Clean project + Rebuild.